# Loop with two conditionals always true

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have an app where I'm checking the location of the user, and if they're close (less than .05 m) they can click a div, if they are far (more than .05 m), they are not able to click it.

The problems is that I have different coordinates for different places, and if you're in one of those you should be able to click it. This makes the conditionals true always because for some locations you're gonna be far but for one its gonna be true (if you're in bound)

I tried a while statement, which works when you get inside one of the locations, but if you get out it never goes away nor displays my banner.

```
//BEING ABLE TO CLICK DIV
while (distance < .05) {
   restaurantImAt = nameRestaurant

   $('.div-image').attr('src', '/assets/picture.svg')
   $('#div').removeClass('disable')

//THIS DOESNT WORK EVENT IF ITS TRUE IF YOURE NOT OUTSIDE THE .05
   if (distance > .05){
      disableDiv()
      $('.page-intro').prepend(
                            `<p class="outside-location"><i class="fas fa-exclamation-circle"></i> You are currently out of bound</p>
      `);
   }
   break
}
```

I have tried also just doing a `while(distance){` and putting if statements inside but it doesn't work either.

Does anyone knows what would be the best method to use when both conditions are gonna be true?

Comment: *when both conditions are gonna be true* That would be `distance < .05 && distance > .05` - so **never**. Or what conditions are you talking about? Also, I see nothing changing `distance` inside your `while` loop, so if it ever enters the loop, there's no stopping it.

Comment: The inner if statement will never execute.

Comment: @conexxo Yes, I mean that all the time or you're gonna be close to just one or not one at all

Comment: @trognanders do you know why? or what method would be better for this? Because I did noticed that the if inner statement never executes

Comment: `if (false) { if (true) {} }` will never execute the inner if.  And the same if you flip the true/false

Comment: Describing where distance comes from would generate more helpful answers. Are you polling for the location, or do you receive it via a callback? In either case, having a while loop is a bad code smell. It seems like an attempt to make an `event loop,` which is not a usual JS paradigm.

Answer (score 1):

What you fail to understand is that any code outside the `while` loop will **never** be executed any more once the while loop is entered.

Because there is nothing changing `distance` ***inside*** your while loop, the code inside it will keep executing forever.

Javascript is single-threaded and your while-loop, while inside it, will be the only code executed on that thread, which does mean that `distance` will forever keep the value it had when entering the loop, because **any code that could possibly alter `distance` does never get a chance to get executed.**

You can work with a `while` loop, you just need to make sure that the code calculating the `distance` is executed in the `while` condition:

```
 while (getDistance() < .05) { /* do stuff */ }
```

(assuming `getDistance` is a function returning the current `distance`).

Comment: Yeah, I just realized that I wasn't making the connecting that the while statement was always gonna be true and therefore not work. I tried also two while statements and it didn't helped and I don't think its the correct way to do it.

Answer (score 0):

**This code is never reached**

```
    if (distance > .05)
    {
      disableDiv()
      $('.page-intro').prepend(`<p class="outside-        location"><i class="fas fa-exclamation-circle"></i> You are         currently out of bound</p>
    `);
    }
    break
```

Seems there is an issue with how you are calculating your distance between two points, try using this https://m.wikihow.com/Find-the-Distance-Between-Two-Points to find distance between two points

Comment: Im calculating the distance correctly, the thing is I'm looping to check if the position of the person is inside any of my points of coordinates. So if they're inside, one of them is always gonna be true, if not they're all of them false.

But if I put a condition when false, still its always true for the other locations not near (if it makes sense)

Comment: What do you mean when you say you have different coordinates?

Comment: So there's different places where people can click this div. All this locations of course have different coordinates. People should be able to click this div if they're in one of this locations, so I need to check always their locations and how far they're from these locations.

Comment: I get you. Could you explain the app logic in this case, I suppose it provides a better understanding

Comment: From the information you've provided is not really clear what you arr trying to achieve